# Run Multiple SaveChanges in transaction in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

The following code is separated by TWO `.SaveChanges()` calls because I have to run some code in fixed order.

First I have to delete existing stuff then add the newly created data.

1. How can I now assure that both `.SaveChanges` run in one transaction? Should I wrap a `TransactionScope` around the `SaveChanges`?
2. Are my both `SaveChanges()` correct at all?

   ```
   var periodsToDelete = _context.Periods.Where(p => p.SchoolyearId == response.Schoolyear.Id &&
                                                 p.LessonDate >= response.DeletionStartDate &&
                                                 p.LessonDate <= response.DeletionEndDate).AsNoTracking();
   var schoolclassCodesToDelete = _context.SchoolclassCodes.Where(s => s.SchoolyearId == schoolyear.Id).AsNoTracking();
   var timetablesToDelete = _context.TimeTables.Where(t => t.SchoolyearId == schoolyear.Id).AsNoTracking();

   _context.Periods.RemoveRange(periodsToDelete);
   _context.SchoolclassCodes.RemoveRange(schoolclassCodesToDelete);
   _context.TimeTables.RemoveRange(timetablesToDelete);
   _context.SaveChanges();

   _context.Entry(schoolyear).State = EntityState.Modified;
   _context.SchoolclassCodes.AddRange(existingAndNewSchoolclassCodes);
   _context.TimeTables.AddRange(timetablesA.Concat(timetablesAB));
   _context.Periods.AddRange(periods);
   _context.SaveChanges();
   ```

Comment: To put both calls to  `.SaveChanges()`, yes, you would have to wrap a `TransactionScope` around them and call `scope.Commit();` when you're successfully done.

Comment: You should read [Entity Framework documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843#several)

Comment: I don't see why you need two `SaveChanges` calls. Did you get exceptions? `TransactionScope` would be the preferred approach, by the way, not `_context.Database.BeginTransaction()`.